# How to assign dynamic names in Java Android?

Tags: java, android

How do you initialise the name of a `TextView` or any other *Android* component with a name only known at runtime?

For example:

```
LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamicLayout);
linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            String dynamic_name = "myTextView"+i;
            //Create new textView named dynamically
            TextView dynamic_name = new TextView(this);
            //style textView here etc
            linLayout.addView(dynamic_name);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do you initialise the name of a textView or any other Android component with a name only known at runtime?

You can't.

`TextView this_variable_changes` is defined at compile time while `String this_variable_changes` changes at runtime.

> Then how to create a variable amount of textViews based on a number that can only be known at run-time?

Once you've got the amount of `TextView`s at runtime, programmatically create that much `TextView`s and add those to a layout.

You don't need dynamic names by the reason mentioned above. What you can do is to map the received amount to the corresponding number of `TextView`s, i.e. use `Map` with the keys indexed up to the received amount and values of `TextView`s.

Comment: Ok, then how to create a variable amount of textViews based on a number that can only be known at run-time?

Comment: @Jupiter, once you get the amount create programmatically that much `TextView`s and add those to a layout.

Comment: yes, this is exactly the solution I'm trying to implement but stuck on how to initialise the names of the individual textViews. Please see update of question. Thanks

Comment: @Jupiter, you don't need dynamic names by the reason mentioned above. What you can do is to map the received amount to the corresponding number of `TextView`s, i.e. use `Map` with keys indexed up to the received amount and values of `TextView`s.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, but you can create Maps or Arrays to deal with your particular issue.  When you encounter an issue that makes you think "I need my variables to change names dynamically" you should try and think "associative array".  In Java, you get associative arrays using `Map`s.

That is, you can keep a List of your arrays, something like:

```
List<String[]> kList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
   kList.add(new String[3]);
}
```

Or perhaps a little closer to what you're after, you can use a Map:

```
Map<Integer,String[]> kMap = new HashMap<Integer,String[]>();
for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
  kMap.put(k, new String[3]);
}
// access using kMap.get(0) etc..
```

Comment: For my particular use case, what value would you put for each key to represent the textView I need to create?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for me was going to your cmd type ipconfig Copy your IP v4 address and paste in android emulator host

```
http://your-ip-v4-address:3000/
```